# Can we detect other websites of a user on a shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, whois

I use a shared hosting plan which allows me to add multiple websites with one account/purchase. I have one website in the same plan for my work, and one for personal works. I can see both of them in my file manager and they seem to be related (in administration part).

I want to know if any random person on the internet can use WHOIS or other tools to connect these two websites to each other.

There are some tools that show domains of the same owner (using their email) or show other domains of the same DNS. I personally see no reasonable way to do this.

Comment: Have you used WHOIS to find out?

Comment: @schroeder AFAIK WHOIS doesn't provide info. But I asked for WHOIS or any other tools.

Comment: DNS tools, like WHOIS, require that the DNS record contain this information. That information is provided by the domain registrar.

Comment: they can tell that both are served by dreamhost, but not that they are on the same billing plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DNS providers provide "domain privacy" services, if you're using these then chances are you're fine.

However, it does go back to the age old thing of determining your threat model. There are more ways than technical tooling to link together two domains and who might own them. For example, analysing the types of content posted on each, the login/administration times, the language that is used, etc. Again, what's your threat?

You should also consider that hosting two separate things in the same place could be a risk. If you want to keep these things separate badly, I advise hosting them in different locations.

As you stated, WHOIS doesn't come back with any personal information such as an address, administrator email, etc. This suggests you're taking advantage of domain privacy services from your registrar and you're more than likely fine.